# Unable to enter a pod in the gke cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

We have our k8s cluster set up with our app, including a neo4j DB deployment and other artifacts. Overnight, we've started facing an issue in our GKE cluster when trying to enter or interact somehow with any pod running in the cluster. The following screenshot shows a sample of the error we get.

[issued command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuLiE.png)

> error: unable to upgrade connection: Authorization error (user=kube-apiserver, verb=create, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)

Our GKE cluster is created as standard (no autopilot) and the versions are

[Node pool details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBDlo.png)

[cluster basics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TdcH.png)

As said before it was working fine regardless of the warning about the versions. However, we haven't been able yet to identify what could have changed between the last time it worked, and now.

Any clue on what authorization setup might have been changed making it incompatible now is very welcomed

Comment: What happens if you run something like `kubectl get pods`?

Comment: Looking at the release notes, looks like your cluster control plane was recently upgrades to 1.22.  There have been changes with exec and auth (if I recall correctly) which are likely incompatible with your nodepool version (which appears to be way out of date!).

You'll likely need to create a new nodepool and then drain the old one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GariSingh. I'm able to get the pods by using kubectl, I can describe them and so. As you said there must be something that has changed regarding exec and auth. I just posted in [this forum](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Google-Kubernetes-Engine-GKE/Unable-to-enter-a-pod-in-the-gke-cluster/m-p/489323#M338) too, if you happen to check it out there, I'd really appreciate your thoughts on the suggestion given there

Comment: @DiegoMartinez did you find a solution? I'm currently facing the same issue. I plan on moving to a autopilot cluster, but need to access some pods first.

Comment: Something has definitely happened to "apiserver-kubelet-api-admin" as this is now 16 days old.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) could have restricted access based on roles assigned to you, limiting certain actions or resources. Please check in the object browser either role binding or cluster binding.